# image hover with views

Tags: views, media, javascript

I have created 2 image-fields in my content type image-main and image-hover.
The image-main is an album display and when you hover the album cover it must change to the image-hover.

How can I get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this is sounds good, you can nicely use the replacement pattern for the views, and there is nice tutorial for css3 hover effect you can use this. [Click here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) 
After adding two field to your view hide the first image field and use the replacement pattern of the next field.In that replacement pattern you can put the variables as like bellow..this is just an example

```
<div id="cf">
 [fieldone]
 [fieldtwo]
</div>
```

then this two image will wrap with a div now you can add class name to the image tag as shown in the example.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you be more specific with replacement pattern for my views? http://codedesign.be/test/Schermafbeelding1.png

http://codedesign.be/test/Schermafbeelding2.png

Comment: see my edit....